# Too much boiler plate code - Methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, boilerplate

I have a simple `UIViewController` with 9 `UIImageViews`. When each `UIImageView` is pressed a method (or function) is called. This all works fine but the problem is that I have too much boiler plate code now.

In my `viewDidLoad` method I have 9 `UITapGestureRecognizer` to detect when any of my 9 `UIImageViews` are pressed. They then call a method to run. Here is my code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed1:)];
[picview_1 addGestureRecognizer:tap1];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed2:)];
[picview_2 addGestureRecognizer:tap2];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap3 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed3:)];
[picview_3 addGestureRecognizer:tap3];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap4 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed4:)];
[picview_4 addGestureRecognizer:tap4];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap5 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed5:)];
[picview_5 addGestureRecognizer:tap5];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap6 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed6:)];
[picview_6 addGestureRecognizer:tap6];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap7 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed7:)];
[picview_7 addGestureRecognizer:tap7];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap8 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed8:)];
[picview_8 addGestureRecognizer:tap8];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap9 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed9:)];
[picview_9 addGestureRecognizer:tap9];
```

And here are the methods that are being called:

```
-(void)imagepressed1:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.seconddata = screen;
seconddata.page_num = page;
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagepressed2:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.seconddata = screen;
    seconddata.page_num = page + 1;
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagepressed3:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.seconddata = screen;
    seconddata.page_num = page + 2;
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagepressed4:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.seconddata = screen;
    seconddata.page_num = page + 3;
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagepressed5:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.seconddata = screen;
    seconddata.page_num = page + 4;
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagepressed6:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.seconddata = screen;
    seconddata.page_num = page + 5;
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagepressed7:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.seconddata = screen;
    seconddata.page_num = page + 6;
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagepressed8:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.seconddata = screen;
    seconddata.page_num = page + 7;
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagepressed9:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.seconddata = screen;
    seconddata.page_num = page + 8;
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

As you can see, my methods are all pretty much the same EXCEPT for one small detail, the Integer called "page" is being increased by a different number depending on the function.

Is there any way I can achieve the same functionality as above but without so much unprofessional copies of my code?

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `picview_N` in an array, and add a different recognizer to them in a loop. Give each `picview_N` a tag that corresponds to the number that you want added to the `page_num`, and use `sender.view.tag` to find that number at runtime:

```
NSArray *picViews = @[picview_1, picview_2, picview_3, picview_4, picview_5, picview_6, picview_7, picview_8, picview_9];
NSUInteger tag = 1;
for (UIView *picView in picViews) {
    picView.tag = tag++;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed:)];
    [picView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
...
-(void)imagepressed:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender { // Common for all recognizers
    ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.seconddata = screen;
    seconddata.page_num = page + sender.view.tag;
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Nice solution but Xcode comes up with the error "Expected ']'" on the for loop line of code. What is the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff This could be related to the version of Xcode that you are using: if your Xcode does not support the new `NSArray`initializer syntax, you can change it to `[NSArray arrayWithObjects: picview_1, picview_2, ..., nil];`

Comment: Well thanks for your solution I still can't get the for loop to work and I can confirm I am using the latest version of Xcode from the Mac App Store V4.6.3. However I did find a solution sort of. I have posted below, its ok I guess. It uses your the method that your provided.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Did you try the `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]` approach?

Comment: Yep it didn't work. I still had the same error with the for loop. Also, I guess the for loop would run in the main loop so wouldn't this approach be bad for performance of the app?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff I made an edit to the header of the loop, I used Java syntax by mistake :)

Comment: @Supertecnoboff As far as performance goes, the loop has very little overhead, and it would also run only once, when you do the setup, so there should be no performance implications.

Comment: Ah right. Thanks. It worked perfectly and is WAY better than my crappy solution. Thank you so much for your help. And the idea of using the tags is very clever. Thanks :)

Comment: Man this is such a perfect solution. No copied code, no performance implications as the for loop only runs once. Brilliant :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use instead is

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

This method ***Returns the farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy (including itself) that contains a specified point.***

So lets say you have one `UITapGapstureRecogniser` set on your `UIView` object and you have tag property set for every  imageview :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewPressed:)];
[_view_1 addGestureRecognizer:tap];


- (IBAction)viewPressed:(UIGestureRecogniser *)sender{
   CGPoint touchPoint = [sender locationInView:self.view];
   UIView *touchView = [self.view hitTest:touchPoint withEvent:nil];
   if(touhView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class] && touchView.tag == 1)
   {
     // Do action on touch of imageview 1
   } 
   else if(touhView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class] && touchView.tag == 2) {
    // Do action on touch of imageview 2
   }
   // similarly for other image views
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution buts its still not great...

```
picview_1.tag = 0;
picview_2.tag = 1;
picview_3.tag = 2;
picview_4.tag = 3;
picview_5.tag = 4;
picview_6.tag = 5;
picview_7.tag = 6;
picview_8.tag = 7;
picview_9.tag = 8;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed:)];
[picview_1 addGestureRecognizer:tap1];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed:)];
[picview_2 addGestureRecognizer:tap2];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap3 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed:)];
[picview_3 addGestureRecognizer:tap3];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap4 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed:)];
[picview_4 addGestureRecognizer:tap4];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap5 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed:)];
[picview_5 addGestureRecognizer:tap5];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap6 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed:)];
[picview_6 addGestureRecognizer:tap6];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap7 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed:)];
[picview_7 addGestureRecognizer:tap7];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap8 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed:)];
[picview_8 addGestureRecognizer:tap8];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap9 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagepressed:)];
[picview_9 addGestureRecognizer:tap9];
```

And as for the method:

```
-(void)imagepressed:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.seconddata = screen;
seconddata.page_num = page + sender.view.tag;
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

If anyone know how I can improve this that would be great thanks.

Comment: To anyone reading this, please ignore my rubbish solution here... Look at @dasblinkenlight solution. Its really good.